# Round table conference with liars

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

In a conference, 8 people (A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H) sit at a round table, all facing inwards.

3 out of the 8 people always lie, while all the others always speak truth.

Here are their 8 statements:

> A: One of my neighbors is a liar, and my other neighbor is not C.
>
> B: One of my neighbors is also a liar, and my opposite person is F.
>
> C: I am not a liar, and my opposite person is E.
>
> D: Both of my neighbors are liars, and even my opposite person is a liar.
>
> E: My neighbors are C and G.
>
> F: My opposite person is B, and one of my neighbors is a liar.
>
> G: One of my neighbors is a liar, and my opposite person is also a liar.
>
> H: Both of my neighbors are liars.

**What is the sitting arrangement? And who are the liars?**

Comment: A, B, F and G could use more precision in their comments, because the English language is a bit fuzzy here: "One of my neighbours is a liar" can mean either "At least one of my neighbours is a liar" or "exactly one of my neighbours is a liar". The interpretation choice will have a huge effect on the solution.

Comment: WHAT DID YOU MEAN BY **NEIGHBOURS**?

Comment: Does "always" mean all the clauses said by the same person has the same truth value? For example, A saying "One of my neighbors is a liar, **and** my other neighbor is not C"?

Comment: @Nautilus, i wrote this around 5years ago ...i don't even remember the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution to the puzzle (I don't have the possibility of graphically representing my solution right now, I will add that later or, if anyone else wants to do that, feel free to add one yourself):

> Sequence A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H (so just clockwise (or counter-clockwise, doesn't matter) in order). Liars are C, E and H.

How I found it:

> I assumed that everyone was telling the truth, unless their statements are contradictory to something someone else already said, going through the statements from A to H. Like that, I found the first contradiction in C's statement (E isn't his opposite person, G is, and thus he IS a liar and lies on both occasions), the second one in E's statement (his neighbors aren't C and G, but D and F) and finally H's statement that his neighbors A and G are liars is also false. Everyone else tells the truth.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> [image]

How I found it:

> I assumed B and F are speaking truth. Then a bit of hit and trials with H. As  if H was speaking truth he could take only 2 places. Placing him on each. It was easy to walkthrough.

Comment: Can I know why my answer was not accepted?

Answer (score 1):

They are located alphabetically (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) around the table.

The truth tellers are A, B, D, F, and G.

The liars are B, C, E, and H.

Like a sudoku, you have to start by testing each statement, and see if the others do not conflict with it. I just started at statement D and saw it on the first try after pairing each letter against its opposite in 2 columns of 4 rows: A, B, C, D & E, F, G, H.

Comment: You have B as both a liar and a truth-teller.

Comment: And if that is fixed, how is this different from the accepted answer?